# How to preserve this value

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

I have reserved bytes that are modified by my assembly routine.

I was using `pusha` /* did my job */ and then `popa` but it results in segmentation fault.

If I replace the `pusha` and `popa` with `push eax` `push ecx` /* do my job */ `pop ecx` `pop eax` it works fine.

But why do I get this seg fault? How is it related to `pusha`?

Below is a part of my code. Here, I only use two out of eight registers. If I need to use eight in my routine, will I need to push and pop each register? Is there no way to do `pusha` and `popa` but keeping buf?

```
main:
   pusha
    mov eax,10
.AGAIN:
    cmp eax,0
    je .END
    mov [buf + ecx],'.'
    inc ecx
    dec eax
    jmp .AGAIN
.END:
    mov [buf + ecx],0
    mov ebp,buf
    call puts
    popa
    ret
```

don't give a seg fault:

```
main:
    push eax
    push ecx
    mov eax,10
.AGAIN:
    cmp eax,0
    je .END
    mov [buf + ecx],'#'
    inc ecx
    dec eax
    jmp .AGAIN
.END:
    mov [buf + ecx],0
    mov ebp,buf
    call puts
    pop ecx
    pop eax
    ret
```

**buf** is defined as:

segment readable writeable
buf  rb 12

Comment: I'm not familiar with Linux and I assume that's what you use because of the seg fault reference, but I'm surprised this second version works for you because you seem to be trashing the EBP register.

Comment: What did you mean with `trashing`?

Comment: I mean that most environments demand that a called function preserve the value of the ebp registry across calls and yours does not seem to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pusha/popa save the 16-bit registers (AX, BX, CX, DX, SP, BP, SI, DI). You are changing the 32 bit registers EAX and ECX so use the 32 bit equivalent: pushad and popad.

Comment: Could be. I'd check disassembly to see whether or not POPA and PUSHA are prefixed.

Comment: Actually,the fasm assembler automatically generates the appropriate
version for current mode. It's according to flat assembler 1.70 Programmer's Manual

Comment: PUSHA and POPA action depends on the mode of FASM. In use32, they are 32bit, in use16 - 16 bit. It is always better to use the full instructions: pushaw/popaw or pushad/popad (although using 16 bit form in 32bit mode is not recommended).

Comment: @johnfound: Was what I said,in others(from the manual) words.